# How does git revert works

Tags: git

I have a file with following history of commits:

```sh
$git log --oneline
49740e5 3: Third version
796a330 2: Second version
539aa76 1: First version
647d060 file C creation
```

In each version I just added a text string to my file.
I though that if I revert "796a330 2: Second version" git will generate a revert commit automatically
and I will get something like this:

```
3: Third version
1: First version
file C creation
```

BUT actually this action was not automatic and I had a merge conflict to solve. Why?

Comment: The [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) explains it: *Note: git revert is used to record some new commits to reverse the effect of some earlier commits (often only a faulty one). If you want to throw away all uncommitted changes in your working directory, you should see git-reset*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git revert causes merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713730/git-revert-causes-merge-conflict)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git revert: Why do I get conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275070/git-revert-why-do-i-get-conflicts)

Answer (score 1):

With `git revert 796a330`, `796a330 2` won't disappear from the log. Instead, another commit is created, which tries to apply the reversed patch of `796a330 2` onto `49740e5 3`.

As to the conflicts, here's an example. Suppose that in `539a76 1` `C` is empty. Then in `796a330 2`, a line `hello\n` is added. And then in `49740e5 3`, the line is replaced with `world\n`.

The patch of `796a330 2` is from nothing to `hello\n` and the patch of `49740e5 3` is from `hello\n` to `world\n`. The reversed patch of `796a330 2` is from `hello\n` to nothing. When the reversed patch is to be applied onto `49740e5 3`, it can't find `hello\n` in `C` as `C` only has `world\n`. So it reports the conflicts.

In other words, the changes of `49740e5 3` are dependent on `796a330 2`'s changes. If you want to revert `796a330 2`'s changes without conflicts, you need to revert `49740e5 3` first. If the two sets of changes are independent, `git revert 796a330` won't cause conflicts in this case.

Conflicts are not errors. You can just solve them by preserving the codes you want and removing the codes you don't. The conflicting marks should always be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, it uses the same machine that is used for merging, except that instead of using `a late "common" ancestor` as the base for merging 2 branches, it uses the revision you ask to revert as the base for the merge and the parent of that revision as if it were `the other branch`. Message is a template talking about what is being reverted..... and then, of course, conflicts have a different "meaning" from a merge.

http://ezconflict.com/en/conflictsse12.html#x53-890001.7

Full disclosure: my material (no monetization, no cookies, no tracking)

Answer (score 0):

The `git revert` command actually is implemented by adding a *new* commit to the HEAD of your branch which functionally undoes whatever the commit you mention to it.  So, your history after calling `git revert` would actually look like this:

```
$ git log --oneline
abcdefg revert 796a330
49740e5 3: Third version
796a330 2: Second version
539aa76 1: First version
647d060 file C creation
```

Now your branch should behave as if the `796a330` commit were never made at all.  One reason for using this approach to reverting a commit is that it avoids *rewriting* your history.  Note that you *could* also literally remove/excise the `796a330` commit using something like an interactive rebase.  But, this would reuqire force pushing your branch, which in turn could cause problems for anyone else who has checked out and is using a version of the branch with the older history.